# I couldn't publish the HTML code containing the Javascript in my Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have been trying to add HTML code containing Javascript from an Affiliate platform to my blog site.

I copy pasted the code from Klook/Headout site (affiliate platform) and pasted in the HTML code blocks. But after pasting the code, the wordpress editor shows the preview of the code within the block editor but not on the actual preview page. When I hit publish it throws errors such as - The response is not a valid JSON response, Server error(403 error), the firewall like cloudfare etc., in your site isn't allowing to publish. I tried again by removing the script tag, by this way it allows me to publish the code. Fyi: I am not a pro in coding.

Issue showing in the browser console.

[image]

```
<ins class="klk-aff-widget" data-wid="55897" data-adid="819231" data-actids="16870,1109,3227" data-prod="mul_act" data-price="false" data-lang="" data-width="336" data-height="280" data-currency=""><a href="//www.klook.com/">Klook.com</a></ins>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function (d, sc, u) {
    var s = d.createElement(sc),
      p = d.getElementsByTagName(sc)[0];
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = u;
    p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
  })(
    document,
    "script",
    "https://affiliate.klook.com/widget/fetch-iframe-init.js"
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the html and js code so I can test it?

Comment: The error is likely on the iframe. Possibly an issue with security the klook site needs to fix. Ask them

Comment: @AdamBasha it is the same code as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Update the question by [edit]ing it

Comment: @mplungjan It would be really helpful If you can share how this issue can be sorted out. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea since I do not use WordPress. I see on your screen shot: "Third party cookies will be blocked" but I do not get errors here: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/daowp4n8/